# Updating mongoose subSchema Object

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, subdocument

My Schema is like this

```js
const subSchema = new Schema({ /*...*/ })

const mainSchema = new Schema({
  //...,
  foo:{
    type:subSchema,
    default:{}
  }
})

const Model = model('Model', mainSchema)
```

If I am doing this the whole `foo` get replaced by `req.body`

```js
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,{ foo:req.body }, { new:true,runValidators:true })
```

But I want that the only fields present in `req.body` get replaced and the rest remain same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an variable that contains fields to update from `req.body` first. Something like:

```
let update = Object.keys(req.body).reduce((acc, cur) => {
   acc[`foo.${cur}`] = req.body[cur];
   return acc;
}, {});

Model.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, update,...
```

Answer (score 0):

You case use mongoose projection :

```
 Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id, 'foo._id': fooId },
  { $set: { 'foo.$': req.body } }
);
```

Mongoose params projection :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find

MongoDB projection :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/